# Typescript structure for methods returning values

Tags: typescript

I'm working with Typescript for the first time and trying to make sure everything is as strict as possible - but I'm having difficulties getting the correct syntax.

The below structure is fine and works well.

```
module blah {
    export class MyFirstClass {
    someVar : string;
    constuctor( value : string ) {
        this.someVar = value;
    }

    firstMethod = () => {
        //does stuff
    }

    secondMethod = ( data : string ) => {
        //does more stuff
    }
    }
}
```

But if I then wish to get one of the methods to return an item, I can't seem to get the syntax correct.  I can get it to return an item *(just add return blah; )*, but I'm trying to make sure that Typescript knows I'm returning something and what type I'm returning.

Reading online seem to suggest the following - but the compiler complains about it.

```
secondMethod = ( data : string ) => string {
    //does more stuff
    var myUpdatedString : string;
    return myUpdatedString;
}
```

Comment: Just a note, you may wish to do `function secondMethod(data: string): string {  }` instead, which creates one instance of the method on the class's prototype instead of using an arrow function, which will create a new instance of the method every time a class instance is constructed.

Comment: That's good to know - thanks JKillian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We should use "**:**" to specify return type:

```
export class MyFirstClass {
  //...

  //secondMethod = ( data : string ) => string {
  secondMethod = ( data : string ) : string => {
    //does more stuff
    var myUpdatedString : string;
    return myUpdatedString;
  }
}
```

Check it [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=export%20class%20MyFirstClass%20%7B%0A%20%20%2F%2F...%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%2F%2FsecondMethod%20%3D%20(%20data%20%3A%20string%20)%20%3D%3E%20string%20%7B%0A%20%20secondMethod%20%3D%20(%20data%20%3A%20string%20)%20%3A%20string%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2Fdoes%20more%20stuff%0A%20%20%20%20var%20myUpdatedString%20%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20myUpdatedString%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D) at playground

Comment: so simple... should have guessed it. Good examples seem thin on the ground for Typescript.